# How to run function on returned text from tkinter text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

My tkinter gui is using text widget and the following code is how I `.get` the data entered.

```
def all_descriptions():
    data = customer_description.get("1.0", END)
    print(data)
```

If user enters:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

It returns the values exactly like that.

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

In an attempt to have the values returned in LIST format, I've also altered the `.get` function to be the following:

```
def all_descriptions():
    data = [customer_description.get("1.0", END)]
    print(data)
```

When I do this, it returns the entries like this:

```
['Item 1\nItem 2\nItem 3\n\n']
```

I have a couple questions for this process even though I've read through countless google and stackoverflow threads.

1. Is the data entered returned as string values? I found a post mentioning this but want to verify.
2. How can I access this data to run my functions on? I've tried this several different ways but my most recent attempt is below.

```
original_description = (all_descriptions())

# Product for Item One
def item_product(original_description, product_dict):
    for key in product_dict :
        if key in original_description():
            return product_dict[key]
    return ("What product is this?")
print(item_product(original_description, product_dict))
```

The above will obviously not work since I want to run the `def item_product()` on each line in the entry widget. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`customer_description.get("1.0", END)` returns a single string. If you want a list of lines rather than a string, split on the newline character with [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)

Also, you should use `"end-1c"` instead of `"end"` or `END`. The latter will get an extra newline that tkinter automatically adds.

```
return customer_description.get("1.0", "end-1c").split("\n")
```